# How to add keys in react

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to do someething like

```
class Example exports React.Component{
   state = {
       items = {},
       id = 0,
       template = {"id":0, "itemName":""}
   }
   addItem = (name) => {
       let item = {...this.state.template,"id":this.state.id,"itemName":name };
       this.setState({items["item0"]:{item}});
   }
   render()/*code*/
}
```

but i cant add a key to the dictionary using setState :c

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator to include the existing items, then add your new item under its key:

```js
setState({
  items: {
    ...items,
    “item0”: item
  }
}
```

If you need to compute the key you can use the [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) bracket syntax:

```js
const itemId = 'bananas';

setState({
  items: {
    ...items,
    [itemId]: item // equivalent of 'bananas': item
  }
}
```

Or use an array:

```js
setState({
  items: [
    ...items,
    item
  ]
}
```

Comment: is there a way that i can change the key depending on  the id? like

`
class Example exports React.Component{
   state = {
       items = {},
       id = 0,
       template = {"id":0, "itemName":""}
   }
   addItem = (name) => {
       let item = {...this.state.template,"id":this.state.id,"itemName":name };
       this.setState({items[`item ${this.state.id}`]:{item}});
   }
   render()/*code*/
}
`

Comment: yes. use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) like `{ [someIdVar]: someValue }`.

Comment: updated answer with computed property name example.